# Session.openActiveSession only calls OPENING in Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to login with Facebook using the Facebook Android SDK, however, the status callback is fired only once with `OPENING` session state. After that, a Facebook login activity appears with no content (I know it's that activity as it has the title that I've set for `title_facebook_login` in strings.xml) for a brief moment and disappears within a second. No other callback is fired, no exceptions, no crashes. It just waits forever at my initial activity. Here is my code:

```
Session.openActiveSession(parent, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if(state == SessionState.OPENED){
                String accessToken = session.getAccessToken();
            }
        }
    });
```

Why wouldn't the callback fire for `SessionState.OPENED` (or CREATED, or even CLOSED) but only OPENING?

Comment: are your calling your Session in your onActivity result code?

Comment: No, it's on `onCreate`. Should it be on `onActivity`? I am very new to Android, so forgive me if its something trivial.

Comment: did you follow the facebook tutorials? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: Not exactly.. I didn't think the firing of the session state would be tied to the view... but apparently I was wrong :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call **onActivityResult**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

So when login done . It comes to same activity and calls status callback with **session state is opened**

initialize **UiLifecycleHelper**

```
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
```

in oncreate need to call before **setContentView**

```
uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

and need to maintain session in

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick. I didn't override the `onActivityResult` method in my activity. I've did it and it fired `OPENED`.

Comment: Thank you , this helped to to log in ...ONCE...then the button changed to a log out button - I pushed it and I logged out....but then the button changed back to log in and pressing it just logs me out again....what am I doing wrong?