# Update Facebook SDK session with a new AppID on Android (using Cordova/PhoneGap)

Tags: android, cordova, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

We have a Cordova/PhoneGap app for Android where users can log in with their Facebook account using the PhoneGap Facebook Connect plugin (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin).

However, we need to programmatically update the Facebook session with a new AppId/AppName every time the user changes the country in the settings, because we have different Facebook apps for every country.

We could get it working creating a custom plugin connected to the Phonegap Facebook Connect plugin that is called everytime the user changes the country or tries to log in with Facebook:

```
package com.OURAPP.facebook;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaArgs;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.Activity;

import com.facebook.Session;

public class FacebookConnectMultiPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    private Activity context;

     @Override
     public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
         context = cordova.getActivity();
     }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, CordovaArgs args, CallbackContext callbackContext)  throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("changeAppId")) {
            String appId = args.getString(0);
            Session session = new Session.Builder(context).setApplicationId(appId).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            callbackContext.success();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

However, after updating the Phonegap Facebook Connect to the last version (now it uses the new Facebook SDK), our custom plugin stopped working and we cannot figure out what is wrong.

## tl;dr

In case it helps, we had the same issue on iOS but we could solve it. In that case we were missing to update the Facebook AppName, however, we couldn't find any way to do that on Android.

This is our old code:

```
#import "FacebookConnectMultiPlugin.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface FacebookConnectMultiPlugin ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *appid;

@end

@implementation FacebookConnectMultiPlugin

- (void)changeAppId:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
    NSString* myarg = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"This is the app id: %@", myarg);

    FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:myarg
        permissions:nil
        defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
        urlSchemeSuffix:nil
        tokenCacheStrategy:nil];

    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];

    if (myarg != nil) {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    } else {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:@"Arg was null"];
    }

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

@end
```

And this is the new code:

```
#import "FacebookConnectMultiPlugin.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface FacebookConnectMultiPlugin ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *appid;

@end

@implementation FacebookConnectMultiPlugin

- (void)changeAppId:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
    NSString* myarg = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* myDisplayName = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:1];

    NSLog(@"----------------------");
    NSLog(@"This is the app id: %@", myarg);
    NSLog(@"This is the display name: %@", myDisplayName);
    NSLog(@"----------------------");

    FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:myarg
        permissions:nil
        defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
        urlSchemeSuffix:nil
        tokenCacheStrategy:nil];

    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
    
    [FBSettings setDefaultAppID:myarg];
    
    [FBSettings setDefaultDisplayName:myDisplayName];

    if (myarg != nil) {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    } else {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:@"Arg was null"];
    }

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a different Facebook app, that the user needs to switch to, then they would need to authorize that app as well. If they're already logged in, you need to log them out by calling `Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation()`.

Then you can build the session like you're doing with the Session.Builder, but then you'd have to open it with an OpenRequest. See how session.openForRead is called [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook#permissions-basic).

Also you'll have to use a UiLifecycleHelper and implement the onActivityResult, you can see a more detailed explanation in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321360/session-openactivesession-only-calls-opening-in-facebook-android-sdk).